# Can't get Prism 8 with DryIoc RegisterServices and Platform-Specific support to work

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, dryioc, httpclientfactory

Trying to use Prism 8, ContainerLocator, IHttpClientFactory and Platform-Specific Service registration with DryIoc Extensions (not Magician) in a Xamarin Forms application

I have these nuget packages installed

```
Prism.DryIoc.Extensions
Prism.Forms
```

My main Xamarin Application inherits from PrismApplicationBase.

In platform code (eg Android) I have IPlatformInitializer implented by MainActivity and for platform-specific services I use:

```
LoadApplication(new App(this));
```

as documented here:
https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/platform-specific-services.html

This line causes the IContainerExtension to be resolved in the shared code

```
protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
```

...but I can't find a way to successfully return a valid IContainerExtension implementation.

I've attempted:

https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/container-locator.html

```
var createContainerExtension = () => new DryIocContainerExtension();
ContainerLocator.SetContainerExtension(createContainerExtension);
```

But the code given here can't even compile - the DryIocContainerExtension class created is defined INTERNAL and isn't available to my application code.

If I use...

```
PrismContainerExtension.Init();
```

or

```
return ContainerLocator.Current;
```

...as worked previously (eg Prism 7.2) I get a runtime error as described here:
https://githubmemory.com/repo/dansiegel/Prism.Container.Extensions/issues/180

```
ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.
```

Please can someone advise what I'm doing wrong, or do I have to get my company to pay for Magician to resolve my issue?

Comment: Hi @Dave R - a LONG time since you posted this so I know I'm asking a lot... but can you remember if you got this issue resolved? Similarly I had it working with Prism 7.2 but after moving to 8 I get same error!